# What is considered to be the natural (injective) homomorphism $\frac{IL+J}{IL} \rightarrow I \otimes \frac{R}{L}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, tensor-products, tensors

Let $R$ be a ring and $I,J,L \unlhd R$ such that $J \subseteq I$.

> What is considered to be the natural homomorphism $\frac{IL+J}{IL} \rightarrow I \otimes \frac{R}{L}$ ?
>
> Remark: It must be injective!

Will $x + IL \mapsto x \otimes L$ or $x+IL \mapsto 0 \otimes (x+L)$ work?

We also have $x+IL \mapsto x \otimes (x+L)$ but this isn't a homomorphism.

What can I take here? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall for an $R$-module $M$ and $\mathfrak{a}$ ideal of $R$ the canonical isomorphism
$$M \otimes_R R/\mathfrak{a} \cong M/\mathfrak{a}M$$
In particular
$$I \otimes R/L \cong I/IL$$
since $IL+J \subset I$, you have the inclusion $$\frac{IL+J}{IL} \to \frac{I}{IL} \cong I \otimes \frac{R}{L}$$

Comment: The purpose of this question is to prove that $0 \rightarrow \frac{IL+J}{IL} \rightarrow I \otimes \frac{R}{L} \rightarrow \frac{I}{J} \otimes \frac{R}{L} \rightarrow 0$ (where we consider the natural homomorphisms) is exact. The $2nd$ arrow is clearly $p \otimes id$ where $p$ is the canonical epimorphism. I'm aware that taking isomorphisms we have the sequence $0 \rightarrow \frac{J}{IL \cap J} \rightarrow \frac{I}{IL} \rightarrow \frac{I/J}{L(I/J)}  \rightarrow 0$ which is exact (with the natural homomorphisms that I know), but it does not imply that the first is exact...

Comment: So, what we define to be the isomorphism $\frac{I}{IL} \rightarrow I \otimes \frac{R}{L}$? I know that the inverse is given by $x \otimes (r+L) \mapsto rx+IL$

Comment: It's $i+IL \mapsto i \otimes (1+L)$.